# text file that changes, display like a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

This is a bit hard to explain but i'll try my best, so I'm a streamer and when a subscriber/follower enters my chat, a text file on my pc gets overwritten with their username, i'd like to create a page that shows a div box each time the file is overwritten, and display the contents of the txt file in the div, after say 5 seconds i'd like that div to disappear, my main issue is i'm not sure where to start, any advice would be amazing

expected results are:
follower join stream

### text file gets updated with their username

(from here on the script)
script see's txt file is changed
displays txt file contents in div

### div vanishes after 5 seconds

current (quick) code snip

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "5";
$_GET["code"] = $code;
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>?code=<?php $md5file ?>'">
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php

$filename = "test.txt";
$md5file = md5_file($filename);


          if ($code!==$md5file){
              $myfile = fopen("G:\Desktop\Stream\Greetings-List.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
              echo fread($myfile,filesize("G:\Desktop\Stream\Greetings-List.txt"));
                fclose($myfile);
          }

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will this be happening locally on your own computer?

Comment: yes, with XAMPP to run it all

Comment: Perhaps you could use AJAX to execute a PHP script that checks the modified date of the text file and returns new messages to your JavaScript.

Comment: i've updated with what i have so far, super basic and very bad but its a start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this isn't pretty but it works, here is what I ended up with.
PLEASE NOTE: this is only being used locally

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "5";
$code = $_GET["code"];

$filename = "Greetings-List.txt";
$md5file = md5_file($filename);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>?code=<?php echo $md5file ?>'">
    </head>
    <body>

<?php
          if ($code != $md5file){
              echo '<div class="greeting">';
              $myfile = fopen("Greetings-List.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
              echo fread($myfile,filesize("Greetings-List.txt"));
                fclose($myfile);
              echo '</div>';
          }

?>
    </body>
</html>
```